# Instrumentation using ByteBuddy is not working on 3-rd party classes

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy

Instrumentation using ByteBuddy is not working when I tried to instrument 3-rd party classes

I manage to create code which instrument my own code and everything worked as expected.
When I tried to use the same code for class which are part of 3-rd party dependencies the instrumentation didn't work.

This code is working for me:

```java
public class A {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("in class A method 'print'");
    }
}
```

```java
public class AgentLoad {

    public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {

        final ElementMatcher.Junction<NamedElement> matcher = ElementMatchers.named("com.instrumentation.A");

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(matcher)
                .transform( new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                        .include(AgentLoad.class.getClassLoader())
                        .advice(named("print"), AAdvice.class.getName()))
                .installOn(inst);
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      AgentLoader.loadAgentClass(AgentLoad.class.getName(), null);
  }

    public static class AAdvice {

        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void enter() {
            System.out.println("Enter Yes!!!!");
        }

        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        public static void exit() {
            System.out.println("Exist Yes!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not working for me:

```java
       public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        AgentBuilder builder = new AgentBuilder.Default();
        builder.type(ElementMatchers.named("com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient"))
                .transform( new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                        .include(AgentLoad.class.getClassLoader())
                        .advice(ElementMatchers.named("execute").and(isAnnotatedWith(SdkInternalApi.class)),
                                AmazonHttpClientAdvice.class.getName()));
        builder.installOn(inst);
    }

    public static class AmazonHttpClientAdvice {

        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void executeEnter(@Advice.Argument(0) Request<?> request) {
            System.out.println("Eenter !!!" + request);
        }


        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        public static void exit(@Advice.Return(readOnly = false, typing = DYNAMIC) Object returned) {
            System.out.println("Exist !!!! " + returned);
        }
}
    }
```

The expected result is a print of enter and exit when calling the 'execute' in class AmazonHttpClient.

Note: The agent is dynamically attached using the next lib: https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-agent-loader

Answer (score 0):

Byte Buddy's API is immutable, all method calls are without side-effects but only return a new builder instance. This means that:

```
AgentBuilder builder = new AgentBuilder.Default();
builder.type(ElementMatchers.named("com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient"))
  .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
               .include(AgentLoad.class.getClassLoader())
               .advice(ElementMatchers.named("execute").and(isAnnotatedWith(SdkInternalApi.class)),
                       AmazonHttpClientAdvice.class.getName()));
builder.installOn(inst);
```

does not do anything. You need to reassign the result of the builder chain to the builder variable again or call `installOn` within the chain.